# Fix " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto3 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for boto3"

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm struggling installing installing Boto3 library.

- **Python version: 3.6.12**
- **pip version 9.0.1**
- **Server: Redhat 7.9 (Maipo) , Fedora.**

I tried different comibnation to get the boto3 library:

- pip3 install boto3
- pip3 install boto
- pip3 install --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple boto3

but always I have the same error.

Any idea?

My code:

```
sla82716:/home/pa009999/scriptDirectory $ pip3 install boto
Collecting boto
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8fb0f74e10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto/
      Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8fb0f74208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto/
      Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8fb0f742b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto/
      Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8fb0f74320>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto/
      Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8fb0f743c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto/
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for boto
    sla82716:/home/pa009999/scriptDirectory $ pip3 install boto3
    Collecting boto3
      Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f08a5642f98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f08a5642438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f08a5642400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f08a56420b8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f08a5642630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto3 (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for boto3
    sla82716:/home/pa009999/scriptDirectory $ pip3 install --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple boto3
    Collecting boto3
      Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5456b85358>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5456b85828>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5456b85898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5456b85ef0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5456b85198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/boto3/
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto3 (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for boto3
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem that there are no versions available but that you have connection issues, probably because it could not resolve the hostname. Could you try `ping google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8` and check if these succeed?

Comment: `# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
sla82716:/root # ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
123 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 122004ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you cannot resolve the hostname. Try adding the following line (Google nameserver)

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file (e.g., by using `nano /etc/resolv.conf`). You can only add three nameservers, so you might have to delete/change one line if there are already three nameservers in the file.

Afterwards, `ping google.com` should work and `pip install boto3` as well.

Comment: I cant modify this file, ACCESS DENIED,
there is other way to make it work except this solution?

Comment: Did you try `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` ?